# Installed VS 2010 after 2012 and MSbuild paths to target file for web publish is incorrect now

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I had a working build script locally that I could build and publish a VS 2012 WebApplication project with just fine until I installed Visual Studio 2010, I don't get seem to get any real errors but it does not publish at all now it just builds and shows success no errors, I do see this in the ms build log :

> Target WebPublish in file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

I know I am still using the correct version of MSbuild but why is it now trying to use the wrong targets file? Would running the Visual Studio 2012 repair fix this? Is there some registry setting or config setting somewhere for this?

I have spent hours trying to track down why this script that worked before and hasn't changed now doesn't work locally but it is still working on my build server just fine, which made me think of what has changed on my machine since I last ran this build fine locally. Any help or suggestions as always is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Its not just msbuild but some other things might have overwritten. Better you repair VS2012. That should fix everything.

Comment: Repair Visual Studio 2012, Then Reapply Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.

Comment: @jessehouwing Repairing with Visual Studio and then the Update 4 worked, although there was some issues with the Visual Studio repair not wanting to finish because of the Update being in place. Can you post this as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (though lengthy) solution will be to repair visual studio:

- Repair Visual studio 2012 from the Windows' Programs and Features window
- Re-apply Visual Studio Update 4

This will ensure the latest bits are back in the place they should be.